# I need the php script for sending firebase push notification to android

Tags: php, firebase

I'm trying to send push notifications to Android using Firebase and PHP.
I already get the device id but I can't send message from php script I don't know where is my mistake. But I can send notification from firebase console using that device id. Can anyone helo me to fix this php script ???

```
 $title = $_POST["title"];
 $message = $_POST["messege"];
 $uid = $_POST["uid"];
 $fID = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($c_m_db, "SELECT firebaseId FROM      tablename WHERE uid='".$uid."'"));
 $fIDD = $fID[0];
 $url = 'http://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
 $key = "AIz***********4I";

 $headers = array(
'Authorization: Bearer='.$key,
'Content-type: application/json'
);
 $fields = array('notification'=>array('title'=>$title,'body'=>$message),'registration_ids'=>$fIDD);

 $payload = json_encode(array(messege=>$fields));

 $curl_session = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

 $result = curl_exec($curl_session);

 curl_close($curl_session);
 mysqli_close($c_m_db);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting an authorization failure.  You are using the legacy API.  The authorization header uses `key=` instead of `Bearer`.  An example of the legacy and new header is in the [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#update-authorization-of-send-requests).

Change:

```
'Authorization: Bearer='.$key
```

to:

```
'Authorization: key='.$key
```